# The menu si rendered offscreen when clicked from the left button of the navigation bar

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-popup-menu

Is there a way to have the menu  render left-to-right instead of right-to-left?
When clicked from the right button of the navigation bar, it's ok;
instead from the left button, it's rendered off screen.

Comment: Can you post any code example to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: @madox2 yes, here you are: https://pastebin.com/xvwK7V0B

Comment: which navigation do you use? react-navigation?

Comment: @sodik yes reactnavigation.org

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short example how to use popup menu with react-navigation. The menu is rendered in both `headerRight` and `headerLeft` placeholders. It is displayed correctly on both sides:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Menu, {
  MenuContext,
  MenuOptions,
  MenuOption,
  MenuTrigger
} from 'react-native-popup-menu';

const NavigatorMenu = ({ navigation }) => (
  <Menu>
    <MenuTrigger text='...' />
    <MenuOptions>
      <MenuOption
        onSelect={() => navigation.navigate('Page2')}
        text='Navigate Page 2'
      />
      <MenuOption
        onSelect={() => navigation.navigate('Page3')}
        text='Navigate Page 3'
      />
    </MenuOptions>
  </Menu>
);

class Home extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: 'Home',
    headerRight: <NavigatorMenu navigation={navigation} />,
    headerLeft: <NavigatorMenu navigation={navigation} />,
  });
  render() {
    return <Text>Home Page</Text>;
  }
}

const Page2 = () => <Text>2nd Page</Text>;
const Page3 = () => <Text>3rd Page</Text>;

const TopStackNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: Home },
  Page2: { screen: Page2 },
  Page3: { screen: Page3 },
});

const App = () => (
  <MenuContext>
    <TopStackNavigator />
  </MenuContext>
);

AppRegistry.registerComponent('examples', () => App);
```

It was tested on android with:

- react-native: 0.37.0
- react-native-popup-menu: 0.7.3
- react-navigation: 1.0.0-beta

Comment: thanks for your effort, i will try to see if there is any difference between my code but i don't use that kind of header because for that page it does not have one, since its a tab :) its just a "fake header", just a normal view with 3 buttons. I will let you know. Thank you so much meanwhile :)

Comment: @AntonioGallo you could provide some minimal runnalbe code so that I could reproduce it. Anyway, feel free to open new question or update this one.

Comment: i confirm it does not work with react native 0.44.0 when on the left side its offscreen; right side its ok; also MenuContext need flex:1 to work otherwise it screw up. I will try again creating a new project from scratch without navigator and just adding popup menu.

"react": "16.0.0-alpha.6",

"react-native": "^0.44.0",

"react-native-menu": "^0.20.2",

"react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.9"

Comment: i think i found the problem in mixing 2 different menu library while testing :) i better remove node_modules and try again

Answer (score 0):

Solved. During testing i was mixing react-native-menu and react-native-popup-menu. I had both installed. And Webstorm pulled me in imports for both libraries mixing them up.

Comment: So is it finally working with `react-native-popup-menu`?

Comment: @madox2 yes! :)